# Failing to show image

Tags: php, html, image

```
foreach($images as $images):
    echo '<img src="<?= base_url();?>resources/upload/gallery/'. $images->image   .'" />';
endforeach;
```

By this code image name is coming I checked but image is not showing. I have also checked image path is also perfect.

Then why image is not showing?

Comment: What do you mean? It's not loading? Did you check the source? Is the property splitting out the image name? Try a `var_dump($images);` inside your foreach loop. (Never mind, I totally missed that you're not using `base_url()` properly...)

Comment: i can not make img src path in echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($images as $image):
    echo '<img src="'.base_url().'resources/upload/gallery/'. $image->image   .'" />';
endforeach;
```

Comment: I thought that too. I just tested it and it seems like you can use the same name in a foreach like that (never thought to try lol).

Comment: Yes you can, But this is for better understanding. And please mark it how i am concatenating base_url() to the src.

Comment: Haha, I missed that. You win. :)

Comment: Hehe i was somehow expecting that.. :P ..

Comment: echo '<img src="'.base_url().'"resources/upload/gallery/'. $image->image   .'" />'; is not working

Comment: Output is coming like that                                                                         <img src="http://localhost/himalaya/" resources="" upload="" gallery="" noimage.gif"="">

Comment: Code updated, It was an unwanted double quote...